# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

What's going wrong here?

Error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.rs.game.player.content.SlayerTask.getNewTask(SlayerTask.java:81)
```

Line 81 of SlayerTask.java:

```
this.currentTaskAmount = amount[Utils.random(low_tasks.length - 1)];
```

amount it's reflecting to:

```
this.currentTaskAmount = -2;
```

Total code if needed:
    package com.rs.game.player.content;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.rs.cache.loaders.NPCDefinitions;
import com.rs.game.player.Player;
import com.rs.game.player.Skills;
import com.rs.utils.Utils;
import com.rs.game.npc.*;

public class SlayerTask implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3885979679549716755L;

private transient static int[] low_tasks = { // 1 - 60
    1648, //crawling hand - slay lvl 1  || Slayer Tower
    1600, //cave crawler  - slay lvl 10 || Fremmy dung
    1612, //banshee -     - slay lvl 15 || Slayer Tower
    1632, //rockslug -    - slay lvl 20 || Fremmy dung
    1616, //basilisk -    - slay lvl 40 || Fremmy dung
    1640, 1637, //jelly   - slay lvl 52 || Fremmy dung, Slayer Tower
    1633 //Pyrefiend                    || Fremmy dung
};
private transient static int[] mid_tasks = { 
    1605, //abarrant spectre  - slay lvl 60 || Slayer Tower
    //dust devil        - slay lvl 65 || Fremmy dung
    //jungle strykewyrm - slay lvl 73 || Fremmy dung
    1610, //gargoyle    - slay lvl 75 || Fremmy dung
    1627, //turoth                    || Fremmy dung
    1609, //kurask                    || Fremmy dung
    1643, //infernal mage             || Fremmy dung
    6215 // bloodveld                 || Slayer Tower
};
private transient static int[] high_tasks = {
    //desert strykewyrm -    slay lvl 77
    1613, //nechryael -            slay lvl 80 || Slayer Tower
    1615, //abyssal demon -        slay lvl 85 || Slayer Tower
    //grifolapine -          slay lvl 88
    2783, //dark beast -           slay lvl 90 || Slayer Tower
    //ice strykewyrm -       slay lvl 93
    //ganodermic creatures - slay lvl 95
};

private transient static int[] amount = { 1};

private int currentTask = -1;
private int currentTaskAmount = 0;

private transient Player player;

public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}

public void resetTask() {
    this.currentTask = -1;
    this.currentTaskAmount = -2;
}

public String getName() {
    return NPCDefinitions.getNPCDefinitions(currentTask).getName();
}

public void getNewTask() {
    if (player.getSkills().getLevel(Skills.SLAYER) >= 1 && player.getSkills().getLevel(Skills.SLAYER) <= 59) {
        this.currentTask = low_tasks[Utils.random(low_tasks.length - 1)];
        this.currentTaskAmount = amount[Utils.random(low_tasks.length - 1)];
        player.getPackets().sendGameMessage("59<= Slayer level >= 1");
    }
    if (player.getSkills().getLevel(Skills.SLAYER) >= 60 && player.getSkills().getLevel(Skills.SLAYER) <= 76) {
        this.currentTask = mid_tasks[Utils.random(mid_tasks.length - 1)];
        this.currentTaskAmount = amount[Utils.random(mid_tasks.length - 1)];
        player.getPackets().sendGameMessage("76<= Slayer level >= 60");
    }   
    if (player.getSkills().getLevel(Skills.SLAYER) >= 77) {
        this.currentTask = high_tasks[Utils.random(high_tasks.length - 1)];
        this.currentTaskAmount = amount[Utils.random(high_tasks.length - 1)];
        player.getPackets().sendGameMessage("Slayer level >= 77");
    }
}

public int getCurrentTask() {
    return currentTask;
}

public int getTaskAmount() {
    return currentTaskAmount;
}

public void decreaseTask() {
    this.currentTaskAmount--;
}

public boolean isComplete() {
    return currentTaskAmount < 1;
}

public SlayerTask() {

}
```

}

I couldn't find anything understandable on google. It would be great is someone could help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your array of length 1 here:

```
private transient static int[] amount = { 1};
```

However, according to your exception message, you've passed in an index of `1`, which is invalid.  The only index that is valid for this array is `0`.

Either modify your array to be longer, or modify your index calculation so it doesn't yield `1`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this.currentTask = (lowTasks.length > 1) ? 
        low_tasks[Utils.random(low_tasks.length - 1)] : lowTasks[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This still gives the same error though.